# read the csv (into a pandas df) located inside nested zip folder

Tags: python, pandas, zip

I have nested zip folders such that the first parent zip folder is called 29092022.zip.
Inside this parent zip folder, there are two more zip folders named ABC123.zip and ABC456.zip.
Now inside each of these child zip folders, there is a csv which i want to read into pandas.
I am using the below code, however it helps to list the names of the csv.
Can you help to advise how i can read the csv's into respective df's

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import re,logging,os,io

with zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\Users\username\Documents\29092022.zip', 'r') as zfile:
    for name in zfile.namelist():
        if re.search(r'\.zip$', name) != None:
            print(name)
            zfiledata = io.BytesIO(zfile.read(name))
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zfiledata) as zfile2:
                for name2 in zfile2.namelist():
                    print(name2)         

Output
ABC123.zip
ABC123.csv
ABC456.zip
ABC456.csv
```

I understand pandas does have direct capability to read zip's.
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\username\Documents\ABC123.zip',compression='zip')
How can i make use of this on nested zip?

Answer (score 0):

Came across same issue last month myself...

**Step1:**

So what I did basically exracted all the files in zip folder, sub-folder, sub-sub folders... Using below code...

```
import os
import zipfile,fnmatch    
input_data_path = r"C:\Users"    
pattern = '*.zip'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_data_path):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, filename)).extractall(os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(filename)[0]))
```

**Step2:**

Created a data frame with all the files inside the parent folder... using this code;

```
import pandas as pd
lst = []
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(input_data_path):
    for name in files:
        lst.append(os.path.join(path, name))
df_files = pd.DataFrame({"path_filename":lst})
```

**Step3:**

Find you file in data frame: df_files & load using pandas... Using this code;

```
key = "CSV_File_Name.csv"
pdf_path = df_files[df_files["path_filename"].str.contains(key,regex=False)].iloc[0,0]
df = pd.read_csv(pdf_path)
```